# How to set different excel files to different variales from the same folder using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataset, xls

I want to load different xls files from the same folder and set them to different variables. I've done that manually but I wonder that that should be a better way to do it.

Here is my code:

```
import os 
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('/home/marlon/ShiftOne/Previsao_insumos_construcao/dados_de_sao_paulo/insumos infraestrutura/')

insumos_mai2004 = pd.read_excel('Custos_Unitarios_Edificacoes_Maio2004.xls')
insumos_jan2006 = pd.read_excel('Custos_Unitarios_Edificacoes_Janeiro2006.xls')
insumos_jul2006 = pd.read_excel('Custos_Unitarios_Edificacoes_Julho2006.xls')
insumos_jan2007 = pd.read_excel('Custos_Unitarios_Edificacoes_jan2007.xls')
insumos_jul2007 = pd.read_excel('Custos_Unitarios_Edificacoes_jul2007.xls')
insumos_jan2008 = pd.read_excel('custos_unitarios_edif jan 2008.xls')
insumos_jul2008 = pd.read_excel('Custos_Unitarios_Edif (1).xls')
insumos_jan2009 = pd.read_excel('Custos_Unitarios_Edif.xls')
insumos_jul2009 = pd.read_excel('custos_unit_edif_jul_09.xls')
insumos_jan2010 = pd.read_excel('Custos_Unit_EDIF_Jan_2010(1).xls')
insumos_jul2010 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit EDIF Jul 2010.xls')
insumos_jan2011 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit EDIF Jan 2011.xls')
insumos_jul2011 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit_ EDIF Julho 2011.xls')
insumos_jan2012 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit - EDIF Jan 2012.xls')
insumos_jul2012 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit EDIF Julho 2012.xls')
insumos_jan2013 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit_ EDIF Jan 2013.xls')
insumos_jul2013 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit EDIF Julho 2013.xls')
insumos_set2013 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit EDIF COM Deson SET13.xls')
insumos_jan2014 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit EDIF SEM Des Jan2014.xls')
insumos_jul2014 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit EDIF SEM Des Julho2014.xls')
insumos_jan2015 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit EDIF SEM Des Jan15.xls')
insumos_jul2015 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit_ EDIF SEM Des SET 2015.xls')
insumos_jan2016 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit EDIF SEM Des JAN 2016(1).xls')
insumos_jul2016 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit EDIF SEM Des Julho 2016(1).xls')
insumos_jan2017 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit EDIF SEM Des JAN 2017.xls')
insumos_jul2017 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit EDIF SEM Des Julho 2017.xlsx')
insumos_jan2018 = pd.read_excel('Custos Unit_ EDIF SEM Des JAN 2018.xls')
```

Comment: Probably, but SO isn't really about code reviews. Is there a problem with your code? What have you identified as a problem? What steps have you taken to solve those problems? Hint: maybe you read the directory for XLS files and add the details from each to a dictionary? Or maybe you process them in a loop? It depends on what you want to do with this data. We don't know from this description what the requirements and constraints are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing this might be to store the xls files in a dictionary with the desired names as the keys. For example:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['insumos_mai2004'] = pd.read_excel('Custos_Unitarios_Edificacoes_Maio2004.xls')
```

However, this won't really fix the core problem: your naming convention isn't great.

Consider thinking of a way to more systematically define your names to reflect your xls filename, or a way of renaming your xls files to be easily converted into a dictionary key (name).